# Populating ViewModel.List<Model> data in text fields using MVC + jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How does one get text fields to update on a page when a drop down list is changed, when the field data is within a view model IEnumerable?  I need to show the receiver details when the receivers name is selected in the drop down list.

Model:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Company { get; set; }
public string Address1 { get; set; }
public string Address2 { get; set; }
public string Address3 { get; set; }
public string Suburb { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
public string PostCode { get; set; }
```

ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<Receiver> Receivers { get; set; }
```

List Loaded in Controller:

```
var receivers = _context.Receivers.Where(c => c.CustomerId == custId && c.Active).ToList();
```

List placed in ViewModel & passed to view:

```
var viewModel = new NewBitsViewModel
        {
            Receivers = receivers
        };
return View(viewModel);
```

ViewModel in view:

```
@model LittleBits.ViewModels.NewBitsViewModel
```

Drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Receiver.Id,
     new SelectList(Model.Receivers, "Id", "Name"),
     "New...", new { id = "rec", @class = "form-control input-sm" })
```

Text fields to be populated:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><text id="rName">Receiver Name</text></td></tr>
    <tr><td><text id="rCompany">Company</text></td></tr>
    <tr><td><text id="rAddress1">Address Line 1</text></td></tr>
    <tr><td><text id="rAddress2">Address Line 2</text></td></tr>
    <tr><td><text id="rAddress3">Address Line 3</text></td></tr>
    <tr><td><text id="rSuburbStatePostCode">SUBURB STATE PostCode</text></td></tr>
</table>
```

aaand stuck on how to do this, if this is even the right way to get results:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rec').on('change', function () {
        $('#rName').html('Should be Receiver Name');
        $('#rCompany').html('Should be Receiver Company');
        $('#rAddress1').html('Should be Address Line 1');
        $('#rAddress2').html('Should be Address Line 2');
        $('#rAddress3').html('Should be Address Line 3');
        $('#rSuburbStatePostCode').html('Should be the Suburb State & Postcode');
    });
});
```

You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emit your collection to javascript

```
var receivers = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Receivers));
```

One the above call is executed, you can access `receivers` like a normal JS array;

```
var receiver = receivers[0];
```

Assuming `receivers` is available globally, populate your table accordingly

```
$('#rec').on('change', function () {
    $('#rName').html(receiver.name);
    $('#rCompany').html(receiver.company);
    $('#rAddress1').html(receiver.address1);
    $('#rAddress2').html(receiver.address2);
    $('#rAddress3').html(receiver.address3);
    $('#rSuburbStatePostCode').html(receiver.suburb + " - " receiver.state + " - " + receiver.postCode);
});
```

I took some liberty to format your `suburb/state/postCode` :-)

Comment: I must be missing something - Json.Serialize() is not available

Comment: I am afraid I am still stuck on Json.Serialize..  All I have available are Json.[Decode, Decode<>, Encode, Equals, ReferenceEquals,Write] -- Googling like crazy..

Comment: Ended up using var jreceivers = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Receivers); var jreceiver = @Html.Raw(jreceivers[0]); but I'm getting nowhere..  I'll get around this issue another way.  Thanks,